# Need inputs about efficiency of my program for finding duplicates in String

Tags: java, string, duplicates, character

I have developed a java program for checking if a string has all unique characters. 
I am listing it down. I will appreciate if i get inputs about the efficiency of this program as well as any corrections needed to improve this program. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.string.duplicatechars;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CheckForDuplicateChars {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String sampleString = "abcdabxyz";
                boolean allUniqueCharacters = allUniqueCharacters(sampleString);
                System.out.println("Are all characters unique: "+allUniqueCharacters);
        }

        public static boolean allUniqueCharacters(String sampleString) {
                boolean allUniquCharacters = true;
                char[] charArrForString = sampleString.toCharArray();
                Map<Character, Boolean> resultHashMap = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();

                for(char ch: charArrForString){
                        Boolean isAlreadyPresent = (Boolean)resultHashMap.put(new Character(ch), new Boolean(true));

                        if(isAlreadyPresent != null){
                                if(isAlreadyPresent.booleanValue() == true) {
                                        System.out.println("Got repeated character: "+ch);
                                        allUniquCharacters = false;
                                }
                        } else {
                                System.out.println("Character "+ch+ " is being iserted first time");
                        }
                }

                return allUniquCharacters;
        }
}
```

Comment: How much do you know about the input data? For example, will all the characters always be ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`Set<Character>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead. When you attempt to [`add`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) a character to the set, it will return `false` if the set *already contains* that character.

```
for(char c: yourCharArray){
    if(!set.add(c)){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet` to store encountered chars and call `contains(..)` to check if a character has already been encountered.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
char[] charArrForString = sampleString.toCharArray();
HashSet s = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(charArrForString));

return (s.size() == charArrForString.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think `Set` and its variants will be costly compared to a simple array. I could be wrong.

Depending on the range of characters expected, you could create one or more arrays of `int`, initialize all indexes to 0 and set them to 1 for each found character using `Character.getNumericValue()`. You have duplicate character if you come across and array element that is already 1.

By one or more arrays I mean that if the entire range of `int` is expected then you cannot create an array that big but you can have two arrays, one for positive and the other for negative values.